# Groovy .each vs .collect

Tags: groovy, iterator

As part of beginners Groovy workshop, We've been iterating over the following list (**fromJson.secrets**):

```
[[floors:10, street:emaseS, url:http://plywoodpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/kermit_the_frog.jpg], [floors:2, street:emaseS, url:http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lp9bg9Lh2x1r0h9bqo1_500.jpg], [floors:2, street:yawdaorB, url:https://montclairdispatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/broadway1.jpg], [floors:5, street:emaseS, url:AAA], [floors:2, street:yawdaorB, url:AAA], [floors:6, street:albmaR aL, url:AAA], [floors:1, street:teertS llaW, url:AAA], [floors:6, street:daoR yebbA, url:AAA], [floors:3, street:teertS llaW, url:AAA], [floors:4, street:dlirehstoR, url:AAA]]
```

The original plan was to use .collect, however it looks like using .each produced the same results (iterated over the list...). 

**The questions is, can someone help me to understand the difference between the methods in regard to my use case and in general**

each:

```
reversed_streets = fromJson.secrets.each {
    it.street = it.street.reverse()
    it
}
```

collect:

```
reversed_streets = fromJson.secrets.collect {
    it.street = it.street.reverse()
    it
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- `each` is used for side effects (which is your example) and returns the original
- `collect` is used to create something new (e.g. like an eager `map` in Java or other languages)

In your example: `each` returns the input to `each`.  Your code there
manipulates `it.street` in place. So you get back your original list, where
each `street` got reversed.  With the `collect` you create a new list with the
manipulated items. So the apparent result is the same, but the difference is
that you created a new container, but still your original has been tampered
with.

Comment: And the second line in the each is unnecessary as the return value for the each closure is not taken in to account anyway

Comment: @cfrick thanks for the answer! So it wouldn't be possible to call .each over immutable sequence. Right?

Comment: @Vano sure you can.  but if its really immultable, you might not be able to pull that `it.x = somethingnew`. but it's totally fine to do `immutableList.each{ println it }` e.g.