# Modify value of items in a list Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I have a list of lists. The inner lists contain `Car` objects.

```
def myList = [ [new Car(model: ".Model1.", year: 2020)] ]
```

As you can see, the `Car` object has some `.` in its `model` property and I would like to remove them.

What I tried is this

```
myList = myList.collect { it.collect { it.model.replace(".","") } }
```

bu this doesn't work because at the end of this instruction I get this

```
myList = [ ["Model1"] ]
```

This is not what I need though, I need the old objects with just that `model` property updated, so in my case I would still have the `Car` object but with the `model` property updated to `Model1` instead of `.Model1.` How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

---

A solution I found is this

```
myList = myList.collect { it.collect { it.model = it.model.replace(".", ""); return it } }
```

As suggested by @cfrick this works too for me

```
myList.each { it.each { it.model = it.model.replace(".", "") } }
```

Not sure if this is the best solution though

Comment: If you have side-effects, each is better than collect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481872/groovy-each-vs-collect

Comment: Thanks, I used `each` and indeed it works fine for me.